# JSON response: Formatting the JSON response for one list item

Tags: json, python-2.7, rest

I'm trying to print the fourth item in a JSON (being pulled from a REST API) response with one return line after the third item, but there are additional return lines between the third and fourth due to the third item using multiple lines for its output. This is causing the output for item[4] look confusing.

Is there a string function I can perform on the last item?

```
for item in whole:
    print "      " + item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]
```

"name": "Lab Servers"
     "description": "For labs in bldg 32"
"ip":

[

"10.2.3.4"
"10.3.4.5"
"10.4.5.6",

]

"type": "WORKSTATIONS"

Here's the "item" input from the JSON dump:
('"name": "Lab Servers"', '"description": "For labs in bldg 32"', '"ip": [\n                "10.2.3.4/32"\n,\n "10.3.4.5/32", "10.4.5.6/32"\n            ], \n            "', '"type": "WORKSTATIONS"')

Comment: Show your source data as well.  It's hard to interpret the example without this.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Edited to reflect the JSON output

Comment: What is the INPUT.  Show us the values of item[*].

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Whoops, totally missed that part didn't I? I edited the question with the input at the bottom.